# How to stop this query from summing all rows instead of just one?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This stored procedure has 3 functions from two different tables.

1. If the row does exist in table B total the qty fields.
2. If the row does not exist in table B insert it from table A.
3. Lastly sum the qty from table A and Table B and update Table B qty field with the new summed value.

My only issue is the stored procedure sums every row in table B and not the correct row or the new row inserted. Could use some direction to resolve?
Thanks in advance.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[XXXXXXXXXXXX]
    @VendorAccountID int,
    @pocomment text,
    @sqlident int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Rowcount INT;  --newly declared, not assigned. NULL   

    INSERT INTO InventoryMaster_tbl(InvManufacture, InvModel, 
            InvManPartNumber, InvDescription, InvLastPO, InvLastVendor)
        SELECT TOP 1 
            PartOrderManufacture, PartOrderModel, PartManufPartNum,
            PartOrderDesc, POID, VendorAccountID
        FROM
            PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
                        WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum)

    SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT

    INSERT INTO [PurchaseOrder_tbl] ([POVendorID], [pocomment])
    VALUES (@VendorAccountID, @pocomment)

    SET @sqlident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE [PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl]
    SET POID = @sqlident

    UPDATE [PurchaseOrder_tbl]
    SET POTicketNumber = [PartOrderTicketID]
    FROM PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
    WHERE PurchaseOrder_tbl.POID = @sqlident

    INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderItems_tbl(POID, VendorAccountID, POTicketID, 
                        POInvItemID, POLineItemQty, PartManufPartNum, PartOrderDesc, 
                        PartOrderManufacture, PartOrderModel, POType, PODescription,
                        POStatusID, PartRequestedBy, POGLCode)
        SELECT
            POID, VendorAccountID, PartOrderTicketID, PartInvID, 
            POItemQty, PartManufPartNum, PartOrderDesc, PartOrderManufacture,
            PartOrderModel, POType, PODescription, POStatusID, PartRequestedBy, POGLCode
        FROM
            PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl

    UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
    SET InvTotalQtyOnOrder = InvTotalQtyOnOrder + POLineItemQty 
    FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
    INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum ON PartManufPartNum = InvManPartNumber
    WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum

    DELETE PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
END
```

This is the finale result I want to thank all of you for the input:USE

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TestPurchaseOrderCreateNew]    Script Date: 8/4/2016 6:15:02 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[XXXXXXXXXXX]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @VendorAccountID int,
    @pocomment text,
    @sqlident int output

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
      --newly declared, not assigned. NULL   


INSERT INTO InventoryMaster_tbl
    (InvManufacture,InvModel,InvManPartNumber,InvDescription,InvLastPO,InvLastVendor)
Select TOP 1 PartOrderManufacture,PartOrderModel,PartManufPartNum,PartOrderDesc,POID, VendorAccountID
From PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum
)

INSERT INTO [PurchaseOrder_tbl] 
    ([POVendorID],[pocomment])
Values (@VendorAccountID,@pocomment)
SET @sqlident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE [PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl]

SET POID = @sqlident

UPDATE [PurchaseOrder_tbl]
Set POTicketNumber = [PartOrderTicketID]
From PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl
Where PurchaseOrder_tbl.POID = @sqlident

INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderItems_tbl
     (POID,VendorAccountID,POTicketID,POInvItemID,POLineItemQty,PartManufPartNum,PartOrderDesc,PartOrderManufacture,PartOrderModel,POType,PODescription,POStatusID,PartRequestedBy,POGLCode)
Select POID, VendorAccountID, PartOrderTicketID, PartInvID, POItemQty,PartManufPartNum,PartOrderDesc,PartOrderManufacture,PartOrderModel,POType,PODescription,POStatusID,PartRequestedBy,POGLCode
From PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl

UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
    SET InvTotalQtyOnOrder += 
    (SELECT SUM(POItemQty) FROM PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum)
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
WHERE InvManPartNumber IN (SELECT PartManufPartNum FROM PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl)

Delete PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl

END
```

Comment: Show sample data and desired result please.

Comment: Results are all qty on order will add one. so if I run this qry 5's = 6, 9's =10. Expected result is only want one row to be added by the statement of line 62 WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum  Dataset.InvItemID InvManPartNumber InvDescription InvTotalQtyOnOrder
10001 23G6689 I7 Power Supply Module 5
10002 18G3214 LCD Assy 5
10003 11G6542 Key Board 9
10004 23G3315 I7 Mother Board 0
10005 23G6686 I7 Power Supply Module 9
10006 18G3232 LCD Assy 9
10007 11G6587 Key Board 0
10008 23G3311 I7 Mother Board 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you just change your SET statement to InvTotalQtyOnOrder += 1 if all you want to do is increment the count?

Additionally the WHERE clause is redundant because your INNER JOIN used the same column criteria so you would already be limited to that subset of data.

Edit: After discussing the problem I think I have a better idea of your desired result. Try using this update statement instead of the one you have for the 3rd update and see if it does what you want

```
UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
    SET InvTotalQtyOnOrder += (SELECT SUM(POLineItemQty) FROM PurchaseOrderItems_tbl WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum)
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
```

Edit 2: Add WHERE clause to UPDATE to only update records with Manufacturing Part Numbers in the Purchase Order Temp table so that only the new PO will be updated.

```
UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
    SET InvTotalQtyOnOrder += 
    (SELECT SUM(POLineItemQty) FROM PurchaseOrderItems_tbl WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum)
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
WHERE InvManPartNumber IN (SELECT PartManufPartNum FROM PurchaseOrderTmp_tbl)
```

Comment: "Why don't you just change your SET statement to InvTotalQtyOnOrder += 1 if all you want to do is increment the count?" Because the value added may be more than 1. could be any value. 1 + 93 = 94. I'll check the where clause and thanks!

Comment: Okay, without seeing the table structures it's still a bit vague exactly what you are attempting but try changing your WHERE clause on the 3rd step to WHERE PurchaseOrderItems_tbl.POID = @sqlident, that should filter your step to only the new row which is what I think you are after.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's difficult explain. InventoryMaster_tbl does not contain POID field and will never have the POID as it is stored in PurchaseOrderItems_tbl. InvManPartNumber is unique so I need to compare InventoryMaster_tbl.InvManPartNumber  to PurchaseOrderItems_tbl.PartManufPartNum. If InvManPartNumber does not exist insert it then sum qty. If it does exist just sum totals. What it's doing is summing every row. not the specific WHERE InvManPartNumber = PartManufPartNum make sense?  Thanks again.

Comment: I think some of the confusion is in the ambiguity of your use of the word sum. In SQL when you use the word sum you generally mean an aggregate operation to add all the values in a column together. I think that's what you are referring to as total. Is it correct to say that you have an inventory master list of parts, each part being listed once. When the sproc runs you would like to increase the quantity column by the sum (aggregation) of all POs for that part based on Manufacturing Part Number?

Comment: Yea I do miss-use mathematical terms as I am no Mathematician. Yes. But only one Row. What this does is add my qty from purchase ordertmp_tbl to every row in invmaster.all, rows are increased I need for it to compare only one row (if exists) InventoryMaster_tbl.InvManPartNumber to PurchaseOrderItems_tbl.PartManufPartNum

Comment: When you say only one row, that would imply that a purchase order can only have a single part? Would it be more accurate to say you only want to update the rows in the Inventory Master that have parts on the PO, therefore handling POs with multiple parts?